# How to import a module for an Angular 2 app (using webpack) when it's installed from github?

Tags: angular, npm, webpack

I'm using ng2-table and when I install it from npm everything is just fine.

However, I need to use someone's fork of this, so I `npm install` from the fork:

```
npm install constantorbit/ng2-table --save
```

But obviously I need to change something in my app module for importing this now?

It was:

```
import { Ng2TableModule } from 'ng2-table/ng2-table';
```

I tried changing it to

```
import { Ng2TableModule } from 'constantorbit/ng2-table';
```

but to no avail:

```
ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Could not resolve constantorbit/ng2-table relative to /Users/dhaskin/clients/io/val2/val2/src/app/app.module.ts., resolving symbol AppModule in /Users/dhaskin/clients/io/val2/val2/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /Users/dhaskin/clients/io/val2/val2/src/app/app.module.ts

ERROR in /Users/dhaskin/clients/io/val2/val2/src/app/app.module.ts (13,32): Cannot find module 'constantorbit/ng2-table'.)

ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'constantorbit/ng2-table' in '/Users/dhaskin/clients/io/val2/val2/src/app'
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 19:18-52
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
```

Comment: Aha.  When I install from github (as opposed to through the npm distribution) the `node_modules/ng2-table` does *not* appear to be complete.

Comment: you can use git url as the dependancies in package.json - 
`'ng2-table' : 'git@github.com:constantorbit/ng2-table.git'`,  your `import` doesn't change.